# Does web crawler identify cookies?

Tags: cookies, seo, web-crawler

Do web crawlers use cookies, or discard them?

Comment: @perezclark I think you have a good question, but you need to do a lot of rewording of both the question and the title.

Comment: And perhaps drop a few questionmarks...I heard The Riddler was looking for you. Something about how many questionmarks there could be in his town or something.

Comment: Maybe better worded as "Do web crawlers use cookies, or discard them?"

Comment: It does read a bit like "how is babby formed" :)

Comment: :) :) :) I would change my question as you guys want... sorry for that.

Answer (score 5):

A crawler is just a piece of software that downloads files over http, and tries to find further URLs to download more files.

It is up to the creator of the crawler to determine whether they wish to use or ignore javascript and cookies.

Most crawlers, I believe, currently will ignore javascript and cookies, but there is no reason why that has to be the case (and you certainly should not rely on it, say for security reasons)

Answer (score 0):

Crawlers do not react to commands to issue cookies and store them until the next visit to a page.

Crawlers do not execute JavaScript.

Crawlers just read default pages (what gets served with no cookies and JavaScript turned off) and rank them based on what they see.

Comment: Sorry -1 - there are webcrawlers that use cookies - here's the documentation to how to turn it on for IBM's Omnifind - http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/discover/v8r5m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.discovery.es.ad.doc/administering/iiysatcookie.htm

Comment: Then that's new for me. Thanks.

Comment: And as of 2010, some crawlers (e.g. GoogleBot, but also some spambots) have JS, even Flash execution capabilities.